# RecyclerView detaches view still visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Current scenario**

I'm using this library https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview to achieve a parallax effect on a RecyclerView. So far, so good. However I would like get an effect like Google Newsstand where the header is still bellow the cards.

**Problem**

The problem is that RecyclerView (or LinerLayoutManager) detaches the header view the moment the first element of the list touches the top of the parent view:

[image]

As you can see the moment the first cardview touches the top is the moment RecyclerView detaches the header.

I'm sure that there is no problem on the logic itself I get `RecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(0) == null` when the card reaches the top. Proving that the header is recycled.

**Tried Solutions**

I tried many things like:

[ViewHolder.setIsRecyclable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#setIsRecyclable(boolean)) using this method to set the holder to not recycler doesn't do any effect.

[LayoutManager.ignoreView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#ignoreView(android.view.View)) I tried marking the view to be ignored from being discarded and recycling. The result was an exception saying:
`Trying to recycle an ignored view holder. You should first call stopIgnoringView(view) before calling recycle.`

[setItemViewCacheSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemViewCacheSize(int)) Doesn't do anything. Tried calling `setItemViewCacheSize(50)` and it doesn't do anything to the header.

[setMaxRecycledViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool.html#setMaxRecycledViews(int,%20int)) Tried setting the max of recycled views with viewType=HEADER to 0 and it still recycles it.

**Conclusion**

So I question if there is anyway to mark the item for not getting detached until I order so (like checking if it's still visible and then detach it).

There is also an issue on the github about it: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview/issues/7

Comment: Does `setItemViewCacheSize` affect it? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemViewCacheSize(int)

Comment: @darnmason No. It doesn't seem to have any effect. Neither has `getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews()`

Comment: I guess it's the job of the LayoutManager and not the RecyclerView, maybe you'll need a custom one that never detaches the first item.

Comment: You're right about that. I've been working with a custom LayoutManager for the past last days and I'm almost reaching the final solution. However some help would be nice, hence the question.

Comment: im using your library,but when i add a header,sometimes when i open the navigation drawer,header color is lost,van you ehlp me on these regards?

Comment: setItemViewCacheSize(0) helped me with similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new design support library's CoordinatorLayout with your recyclerview and make the same effect with no issues like this.

check this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: That would require a lot of changes, including deleting the whole library and starting a new one, which would be redundant since this is what the support library does in the first place, That is not what it's intended. A better fix could be archived by changing LinearLayoutManager

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?